# Convert for loop to list comprehension

Tags: python, list, dictionary, for-loop, list-comprehension

I am trying to convert my code to a list comprehension, but cannot figure this out

my code:

```
dicts = [
    {"p": 1, "p": 2, "olp": 3, "r": 4}, 
    {"s": 1, "o": 2, "e": 3, "cs": 4}, 
    {"vc":1, "txc":2, "faw":3, "e": 4}
]

l = []

for d in dicts:
    for k, v in sorted(d.items(), key=lambda kv: kv[1]):
        if v % 4 == 0:
            if len(k) > 1:
                l.append(k[1])
            else:
                l.append(k)
        elif v % 2 == 0:
            if len(k) > 2:
                l.append(k[0])
            else:
                l.append(k)
print(''.join(l))
```

I've tried this, but doesn't work, can you help me with it?

```
l = [
    k[0] if len(k)>2 else k elif v % 2 == 0 
    k[1] if len(k)>1 else k if k % 4 == 0  
    for k,v in sorted(d.items(), key=lambda kv: kv[1]) for d in dicts
]
```

Expected output for `l`:

```
['p', 'r', 'o', 's', 't', 'e']
```

Comment: [Ternary operators](https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/ternary_operators.html) are not the same as `if`-statements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reformatted into a one-line list-comprehension, the code is as follows:

```
>>> l = [k[1] if v%4 == 0 and len(k) > 1 else k[0] if len(k) > 2 else k for d in dicts for k,v in sorted(d.items(), key=lambda kv: kv[1]) if v%2 == 0]
>>> l
['p', 'r', 'o', 's', 't', 'e']
```

Or formatted a bit more nicely:

```
l = [
     k[1] if v%4 == 0 and len(k) > 1
     else k[0] if len(k) > 2 
     else k
     for d in dicts
     for k,v in sorted(d.items(), key=lambda kv: kv[1])
     if v%2 == 0
     ]
```

As far as I can tell, you don't need to call `sorted()` on `d.items()` either, so you could omit that unless it's needed outside your MWE.